# What is the minimum seekTo value that a vimeo player can go to

Tags: javascript, vimeo, froogaloop

I am experimenting with different `seekTo()` values in the Vimeo froogaloop api. If the current time is 10 (seconds), I can easily go to 11 with `player.api('seekTo', 11);` , but I am trying to go a fraction of that time. Can I `seekTo()` frames instead of seconds ?

Here is an example of a button that should advance part of a second - specifically a frame if we assume the video is 24 FPS:

http://jsfiddle.net/scroll_lock/SeBwt/8/

But for some reason, the video only goes to whole frames when the "advanceFrame" button is clicked.

Anyone sees any flaw in my code ? Does the vimeo API supports such kind of seeking ?